# How do I set up alerts per Discussion Board in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

In a Sharepoint 2010 site I have a Discussion Boards list.
Now, each discussion board mayb have different participants.
How do I set up alerts that are specific for each discussion board, and not for the whole list?

Thanks.

Comment: I got this one answered in the sharepoint site: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54167/how-do-i-set-up-alerts-per-discussion-board-in-sharepoint-2010

Comment: I got this one answered in the sharepoint site: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54167/how-do-i-set-up-alerts-per-discussion-board-in-sharepoint-2010

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the discussion board home page and click the "List" Menu item from the Menu bar.
2. Next click on "Alert Me" button to customize your alert options. Here you can add contacts to be alerted, notification type, frequency etc.